# Multiple ListBox Selection, dynamically update text based on selections

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a UserForm which populates a multi-selection ListBox (based on a comma-delimited cell from a hidden sheet).

If a user selects a SINGLE item from the listbox, I want a specific note for that item to be displayed based on their selection.

[image: singleOK]

If they select MULTIPLE, I would like the note to ADD the note for the item they just selected to the EXISTING one, without duplicating the originally selected item.

[image: current results]

If a user de-selects the original item but keeps the second item, there is now invisible lines that need to be removed. In addition to the duplication...

[image: blank lines]

Currently my code is:

```
'check for nothing selected
If Driver_Sel = "" Then
    'nothing selected
    lbl_driverID.Caption = ""
End If

If InStr(1, Driver_Sel, "PC-CR") <> 0 Then
    'PCCR format
    lbl_driverID.Visible = True
    lbl_driverID.Caption = lbl_driverID.Caption & vbNewLine & "-PC-CR: use Format: PCCR-0000xxxx/001"
ElseIf Not InStr(1, Driver_Sel, "PC-CR") <> 0 Then
    'remove PCCR
    lbl_driverID.Visible = True
    lbl_driverID.Caption = Replace(lbl_driverID.Caption, "-PC-CR: use Format: PCCR-0000xxxx/001", "")
End If

If InStr(1, Driver_Sel, "PRTS") <> 0 Then
    'PRTS
    lbl_driverID.Visible = True
    lbl_driverID.Caption = lbl_driverID.Caption & vbNewLine & "-PRTS: include a PRTS#"
ElseIf Not InStr(1, Driver_Sel, "PRTS") <> 0 Then
    'remove PCCR
    lbl_driverID.Visible = True
    lbl_driverID.Caption = Replace(lbl_driverID.Caption, "-PRTS: include a PRTS#", "")
End If
```

I think this is because I have the caption for the label (blue text) use it's existing value and then add the new item.. even if it is duplicated.

I'm a bit stumped here... any help on only show one instance of the note?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Just rebuild the entire caption out of the selection everytime a user selects or deselects something instead of add/remove from the caption. That would be much easier and the caption is always fitting to the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lbl_driverID.Caption` should be reset between executions. Otherwise, it just accumulates text every time the list box selection changes.

Try `lbl_driverID.Caption = ""` at the beginning of your If Else block.

For example:

The user opens a new user form. The user selects "PC-CR" as the first value. `lbl_driverID.Caption` is blank and the script assigns it the value "-PC-CR: use Format: PCCR-0000xxxx/001".

Then the user selects something else, but the selection still  contains the first selected value "PC-CR". So the script re-adds the same value to the caption. This is where the double-up is coming from.

For the invisible lines:

That is because you are adding `vbNewLine` to the caption for each new item but you are only removing the text and not the `vbNewline`.
See the difference between these two lines:

```vb
lbl_driverID.Caption & vbNewLine & "-PC-CR: use Format: PCCR-0000xxxx/001"
Replace(lbl_driverID.Caption, "-PC-CR: use Format: PCCR-0000xxxx/001", "")
```

Notice that `vbNewLine` is not accounted for.